# In SQL Server, how do I create a reference variable to a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables, dynamic-sql

I'm currently using sp_executesql to execute a T-SQL statement with a dynamic table name. However, it is really ugly to see something like:

```
set @sql = 'UPDATE '+Table_Name+' SET ... WHERE '+someVar+' = ... AND '+someVar2' = ...'
sp_executesql @sql
```

What I would rather like to have is a TABLE variable of which is a reference to a table, so I could do for example:

```
UPDATE TableRef SET ... WHERE ...
```

Because when I have really long T-SQL statements it gets really hard to read due to the format of it within a string.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: btw, not `SET sql = ...` but `SET @sql = ...`

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the fixes. I kept getting blockquote when I pressed @. I wasn't aware that I could do it like this. Thanks.

Comment: ón: the product is called "SQL Server", not "MSSQL".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you pass the parameters to [sp_executeSQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) instead?

I'd also have a look at [this article](https://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you want to use a dynamic table name in your SQL, you have to concatenate it into your string.

If you have a lot of references to the table name within your query, you can shorten it by aliasing the table name, and for all other instances, use the alias.

e.g.

```
SET @SQL = 'UPDATE t SET.... FROM ' + @TableName + ' t WHERE ....'
```

Just be very very careful when using dynamic SQL like this. Make sure you guard yourself against SQL injection.